# get options value from wp_options table

Tags: php, database, wordpress

In my wp_options table, there is a field called profile_fields, that field is having the values like as given below

```
a:18:{
i:1;a:8:{
s:4:"type";s:8:"usermeta";s:4:"icon";s:8:"calendar";s:8:"position";s:1:"9";s:5:"field";s:6:"select";s:4:"name";s:15:"Graduation Year";s:4:"meta";s:15:"graduation_year";s:11:"meta_custom";s:0:"";s:6:"social";s:1:"0";s:8:"can_edit";s:1:"1";s:10:"allow_html";s:1:"0";s:8:"can_hide";s:1:"0";s:7:"private";s:1:"0";s:8:"required";s:1:"1";s:17:"show_to_user_role";s:1:"0";s:17:"edit_by_user_role";s:1:"0";
    s:16:"show_in_register";
    s:1:"1";
    s:9:"help_text";
    s:0:"";
    s:7:"choices";
    s:22:"1991
        1992
        1993
        1994";

 }
}
```

what I've to do for getting the s22 the field.(1991,1992,1993,1994).
I have tried to dump the values using var_dump(), but it only shows some other fields.

anyone please help me.

UPDATED

I've took option value from the database like this

```
$a = get_option( 'upme_profile_fields' );
        print_r($a);
```

now it prints like

[image]

there it not shows the above given contents(

```
a:18:{
    i:1;a:8:{
    s:4:"type";s:8:"......
```

)

Comment: It's a serialize string, use `unserialize` function to convert it into an array.

Comment: you tried   <?php get_alloptions() ?>   ?

Comment: @Rikesh unserialize expects string parameter. but here we have objecj

Comment: Casted an re-open vote, for the sole reason the duplicate question does not seem to exist anymore...

Comment: @Sumurai8 I have removed duplicate question please remove duplication now

Comment: Re-opening requires 5 users with sufficient reputation to cast a re-open vote (or a moderator who wanders by).

Comment: @Sumurai8 flagged for getting moderator attention

Answer (score 3):

Try this :-

```
$a = get_option( 'profile_fields' );
print_r($a);
// find the value you want to un-serialize, then, put as below

$arr = $a["YOUR VALUE KEY"];

$profile_arr = unserialize($arr);

print_r($profile_arr);
```

Comment: it shows :  Warning: unserialize() expects parameter 1 to be string, array given

Comment: what is value key in the above example

Comment: please paste the result of print_r($a); here

Comment: Array ( [50] => Array ( [position] => 50 [type] => separator [ meta ] => profile_info_separator [name] => Profile Info [private] => 0 [deleted] => 0 [show_to_user_role] => 0 ) [60] => Array ( [position] => 60 [icon] => camera [field] => fileupload [type] => usermeta [ meta ] => user_pic [name] => Profile Picture [can_hide] => 0 [can_edit] => 1 [private] => 0 [social] => 0 [deleted] => 0 [show_to_user_role] => 0 [edit_by_user_role] => 0 [help_text] => )

Comment: in this I am not getting the values I've mentioned in question

Comment: may be you have given the different field name? Do you need "profile_fields" or some other field?

Comment: same I've given, if you provide me your mail id I'll send you the screenshots as well as other files.

Comment: chaturvedikhushboo_13@yahoo.com

Comment: please check your mail